# Will gdisk zap erase my disk?

Tags: installation, dual-boot

My Ubuntu install is not detecting my Windows 7. Some say I need to convert it from MBR to GPT or the other way around. So when I try to zap my drive with gdisk through the terminal, it gives me a warning that it might be destructive or something.

These are the commands I use:

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
z
```

What should I do? Could this erase everything I have on the disk?

EDIT: So when I type `sudo gdisk /dev/sdc` it comes up with a warning that says that I have no GPT partition table, and converting MBR to GPT is "potentially destructive".

Then it asks if I want to continue. So is it destructive? What does this even mean?

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Always keep in mind that when dealing with anything to do with partitions, make sure that you have a current backup, in case something goes wrong.**

Gdisk is a disk partitioning tool, and it can erase your disk if not careful.  It is designed to create, modify, and erase partitions.  As far as converting MBR to GPT and GPT to MBR, keep reading.

One of the more unusual features of gdisk is its ability to read an MBR partition table and convert it to GPT format without damaging the contents of the partitions on the disk.

This feature exists to enable upgrading to GPT in case the limitations of MBRs.

In addition to converting to GPT format, GPT fdisk supports converting from GPT format to MBR format. This feature, though, comes with some caveats: Depending on how the disk was originally partitioned, it may not be possible to convert all the original partitions. Even if converting all the partitions is possible, there may be restrictions on which partitions can be turned into logical partitions, which may in turn result in some odd or undesirable assignments to primary vs. logical partitions in the final MBR partition table.

Unfortunately, a complete conversion from GPT to MBR is tricky.<sup>[Gdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)</sup>

**Note: Always keep in mind that when dealing with anything to do with partitions, make sure that you have a current backup, in case something goes wrong.**